# Unable to make a 'related terms' code using strpos work in PHP

Tags: php, strpos

What I'm trying to do is get an input text from the user (for example lets say 'Java programmer') and trying to match this user input with a list of strings that I have stored in an array like 'Java programmer is a good boy', 'he plays ball at times', 'java and dogs hate each other', ' dogs are not java programmers'

I'm trying to do word matching so the program outputs a list of all strings in the array that match all words in user query (order isn't important)

So I want the output of the below code to be...

'Java programmer is a good boy'
'dogs are not java programmers'

Because these terms contain both 'java' and 'programmers' as per the query the user enters

Here's the code I wrote, it doesn't work. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
<?php
$relatedsearches = array();
$querytowords = array();
$string = "Java programmer"; //GET INPUT FROM USER
$querywords = (explode(' ', $string));
foreach($querywords as $z)
    {
            $querytowords[] = $z;
            }

//ARRAY THAT STORES MASTER LIST OF QUERIES

$listofsearhches = array('Java programmer is a good boy', 'he plays ball at times', 'java and dogs hate each other', ' dogs are not java programmers');

foreach($listofsearhches as $c)
    {
    for ($i=0; $i<=(count($querytowords)-1); $i++)
        {   
        if(strpos(strtolower($c), strtolower($querytowords[$i])) === true)
            { 
            if($i=(count($querytowords)-1))
                {
                $relatedsearches[] = $c;
                } 
            } else { break; }
        }
    }

echo '<br>';
if(empty($relatedsearches))
    {
        echo 'Sorry No Matches found';
    } 
    else 
    {
    foreach($relatedsearches as $lister)
        {
                echo $lister;
                echo '<br>';
                }
            }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this:-

```
$matches = array();
$string = 'java programmer';
$stringBits = explode(' ', $string);
$listOfSearches = array('Java programmer is a good boy', 'he plays ball at times', 'java and dogs hate each other', ' dogs are not java programmers');

foreach($listOfSearches as $l) {
  $match = true;
  foreach($stringBits as $b) {
    if(!stristr($l, $b)) {
      $match = false;
    }
  }
  if($match) {
    $matches[] = $l;
  }
}

if(!empty($matches)) {
  echo 'matches: ' . implode(', ', $matches);
} else {
  echo 'no matches found';
}
```

So loop over the list of strings to search, set a flag (`$match`), then for every word in the `$string` check it exists somewhere in the current `$listOfSearches` string, if a word doesn't exist it will set the `$match` to false.

After checking for every word, if the `$match` is still `true`, add to the current string from `$listOfSearches` to the `$matches` array.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Other than a small typo in "foreach($strBits as $b)" your code works like a charm.

Comment: Sorry about that, I only noticed it myself a couple of minutes ago :p

Answer (score 0):

no need to explode the `$string` as you are looking for both the words java and programmer as a string 'Java programmer'. so your foreach need to look  like this

```
 foreach($listofsearhches as $c)
{   
    if(strpos(strtolower($c), strtolower($string)) === true)
        {            
            $relatedsearches[] = $c;

        } else { break; }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your solution will not work for a string like 'He loves Java and is a programmer' which has both words too but not next to each other

EDIT: No I'm not looking for 'Java' and 'Programmer' as a string. Any occurrence anywhere of 'Java' and 'Programmer' is what I'm looking for and that's why I used explode

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $string = "Java programmer"; //GET INPUT FROM USER
    $querywords = (explode(' ', $string));
    $relatedsearches = array();
    $listofsearhches = array('Java programmer is a good boy', 'he plays ball at times', 'java and dogs hate each other', ' dogs are not java programmers');
    foreach ($listofsearhches as $c) {
        foreach($querywords as $word){
            if(strpos(strtolower($c), strtolower($word)) !== false){
                if(!in_array($c, $relatedsearches))
                    $relatedsearches[] = $c;     

                break;
            }
        } 
    }

    echo '<br>';
    if (count($relatedsearches) < 1) {
        echo 'Sorry No Matches found';
    } 
    else {
        foreach ($relatedsearches as $lister) {
            echo $lister;
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }
?>
```

give it a go

Comment: Thanks for replying! This works, but it matches the string even if one word from the query is in it. For instance, the output I got on running this was..

'Java programmer is a good boy'
'java and dogs hate each other'
'dogs are not java programmers'

Comment: i thought thats what you want .. all you need is bit twist n you can get what you want ... if you still need that i can modify little bit to make it work for you

Comment: I'm sorry about that I think I didn't explain it very well. Thanks, your help is much appreciated but the other code posted 'deifwud' worked.

Thanks again :)